# How can i add a playing tag discord bot heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord

**Help Me**

How can I add a playing tag to my discord bot through heroku  I'm using a github respiratory. And It's Running on node.js and its using its bot token through heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're on v11.3 or master. You can check with `npm ls discord.js` and update `with npm i discord.js`.
Afterwards, use `<ClientUser>#setActivity` to set your bot's status to "Watching ...", "Listening to ...", etc.

```
client.user.setActivity('YouTube', { type: 'WATCHING' });
```

Comment: But I'm using a github respiratory linked to it